# How to Get Files from different repository in Git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository

i have a question about Git. We used SVN before and want to migrate to git now.

We have several projects, each of them in a own repository.

All of those projects need some library flies from one other repository.

1. Repository

../Soruce

../Bin

2. Repository

../Source

../Bin

The second repository now needs some (not all) files from the ../Bin folder from the 1. Repository but in its own ../Bin folder. 
In SVN we solved this with some externals.

we allready tried submodule, witch fails because ../Bin is not a repository.
Than we tried the treemerge but failed because ../Bin allready exists.

We would like to have an reference to the first repository to easily update the second one.
Would be great if we can force an specific commit to be used.

best regards
Cajon

Comment: Cant you move files manually from Repository1's Bin folder Repository 2's Bin folder....

Comment: Yes that's an opinion but takes some time to update those files. It would be nicer to update these files if the source file in repository 1 changes.

Comment: You may consider using git submodules. http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Is there any way to use git submodules without cloning the full repository?